# JavaFX Hibernate returning Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm a newbie here in Stackoverflow and this is my first time putting my questions here since I always research anything about my programming basics.
The problem I am facing now is the Null Pointer Exception. I am working in JavaFX Hibernate for the first time and it seems Null Pointer Exception is absolutely present with my basic practice :( 
 so here is my problem. . I will provide the codes . . hope you will get it :(


//Model(Pojo) Code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
private String lastName; //including the setters and getters here}
```

//Repository Code

```
@Override
public List<Person> getPerson() {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
        String hql = "From Person";
        //System.out.println(hql);
        return session.createQuery(hql).list();
        
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

//Service Code

```
public interface PersonService {
List<Person> getPerson();}
```

Controller Code (where the NPE Persist)

```
 @FXML
private TableView<Person> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, Integer> id;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> firstname;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> lastname;
private final ObservableList<Person> person = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

void getAllData() {
    List<Person> personList = personService.getPerson();
    person.addAll(personList);
    id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id")); //returns NPE here
    firstname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
    lastname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
    table.setItems(person);
}
```

//FXML Code in package 'forms' (forms/FormX.fxml)

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
<children>
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="606.0">
<children>
<TextField fx:id="fname" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Firstname" />
 <TextField fx:id="lname" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="102.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Lastname" />
<Button fx:id="btn_save" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SaveData" text="SAVE " />
<Button layoutX="154.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CANCEL" />
 <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="258.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="324.0">
<columns>
<TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="75.0" text="id" />
<TableColumn fx:id="firstname" prefWidth="75.0" text="firstname" />
 <TableColumn fx:id="lastname" prefWidth="75.0" text="lastname" />
</columns>
</TableView>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error Returns: j*ava.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback)" because "this.id" is null*



I created a Persistence Unit (persistence.xml) the connection is good and I can connect.


 So this is my problem, the "id" always returning NPE and I'm pointing it on the Pojo. I don't know how to get rid of this as I research about this for how many links :( I do hope I can get an answer in this query. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what FXML is supposed to do, but the id field is null. Most likely you are supposed to set it (perhaps in the constructor?) before using it. Alternatively if FXML is supposed to inject a value, check the names as that does not seem to be working.

Comment: @ewramner what do you mean sir?

Comment: Apparently you solved it. I just noted that id was null; you need to set it somewhere or (more likely) make JavaFX inject a value.

Answer (score 0):

So Basically I solved my problem for an hour. lol 
so I put the **`getAllData();`** method in my Controller in the

```
void intialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){//I put it here}
```

it sounds weird but I realized it after a lot of research without finding an answer lol. so I tried to relax and stare at my code then the idea miraculously appear! LOL. I tried to figure it out now what is the problem with my previous logic. the last one I did was putting the getAllData in the main Class or the Launcher after the `stage.show();` and the NPE persist here. if anyone can explain me why cause I can't figure it out. please share your idea to me. thanks